# Webform entries goes to Gmail Spam folder

Tags: webforms, emails

Any submissions from Webform goes to my emails (Gmail) Spam folder... I ask myself if I've configured something not right in the webform form settings... Please give me your valued opinion in the matter, Ben.

Comment: Your question is too vague @Ben.  You need to provide some more information, starting with the settings you're using for your webform and any code you have written.

Comment: It depends on which email address you are using to send email. provide original email address in from email then it might work.